# Issue regarding background color of App title and button in Android Studio

Tags: android

I have attached screenshot of ***activity_main.xml*** and pasted code of ***themes.xml*** and ***colors.xml***

I have observed that the app title background color and button background color is defined by ***colorPrimary*** which is in ***themes.xml*** but I want it to edit it in ***activity_main.xml*** . I tried it but setting background color of button in ***activity_main.xml*** does not change anything and I don't even know how to change app title background color in ***activity_main.xml***. Can someone guide me . How do I have different background colors of app title and button if they are controlled by the same thing ?[image]

themes.xml code

> ```
> <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
>     <!-- Base application theme. -->
>     <style name="Theme.AgeInDays" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
>         <!-- Primary brand color. -->
>         <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
>         <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
>         <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
>         <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
>         <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
>         <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
>         <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
>         <!-- Status bar color. -->
>         <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
>         <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
>     </style>
> </resources>
> ```

colors.xml code

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <resources>
>     <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
>     <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
>     <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
>     <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
>     <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
>     <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
>     <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
>     
>     <color name="backgroundColor">#FFA938</color>
>     <color name="textColor">#844046</color>
>     <color name="ageTextBackgroundColor">#CD46DCE0</color>
>     <color name="buttonTextColor">#B7B7B7</color>
>     <color name="selectedDate">#000000</color>
>     <color name="color_primary">#000000</color>
> </resources>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and Easy Answer:-
Do This:-

1. For Changing Background Color Of Action Bar

`<item name="colorPrimary">//Color of your choice</item>`

2. For Changing Color of Button

`<Button android:backgroundTint="#32a852"/>`

But, I would prefer you to use Toolbar instead of Action Bar.

Comment: Thanks sir for the help !

Answer (score 0):

It's better not to explicitly set the colours in your layout.xml files.
You should try and encapsulate it all in your `themes.xml` file. A lot of the built in components will theme themselves based on the value `Primary Brand Color` and `Secondary Brand Color` that you've posted.

To answer your question:

- The app title background colour (the bar colour) will be `colorPrimary`.
- The button colour will also be `colorPrimary`. I believe the button text will be `colorOnPrimary`.

To add a new colour, simply add a new entry to `colors.xml` with a name of your choice.

`<color name="my_brand_colour">#ff3300</color>`

You can use something like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp) to find the colour's hex value.

Then in `themes.xml` you can update the existing values with your new colour.

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_brand_colour</item>
```

This example will set `colorPrimary` to be red, which will change the bar and button colours along with many more component colours.

Coming back to your issue of setting the button colour, you may have been using the wrong property:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test Button"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/design_default_color_error">
</Button>
```

(`backgroundTint` instead of `background`)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Greg sir !

Comment: No problem, glad i could help!